# How can i instantiate the an object that corresponds to an fxml and a controller

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml, fxmlloader

Let's say that i have a controller Ctr and a fxml file file.fxml that corresponds.
I want to declare and instantiate an object that i can show on screen that corresponds to this fxml and controller.
I have Class A that contains this object.
The problem is:
if declare this object as Ctr (controller) it's no longer showable because i can't add it as a child to others such as stackpane.
And if use FXMLLoader the returned class of load is not known and i can not store it as Ctr object.

Comment: *"if use FXMLLoader the returned class of load is not known and i can not store it as Ctr object"* It's always possible to cast or use the type parameter of the `load` method. This may be an option for you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components

Answer (score 0):

You can not know the return class of the `FXMLLoader` sure but because you choose the `fxml` file you know in which class you have to cast the `controller` :

```
Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
FXMLLoader fx = new FXMLLoader(Paths.get("../specialView4X.fxml").toUri().toURL());
Scene scene = new Scene(fx.load());
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
primaryStage.centerOnScreen();    
SpecialView4XController control = (SpecialView4XController) fx.getController();
```

---

This is for launching a new window, for re-using the existing one same, take an existing object ad use `getScene()` on it